# Verificar si existe una columna en tabla y si no crearla desde PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tengo la siguiente problematica:

Verificar si existe una columna con el nombre que paso por una variable y si no crear con la columna con el nombre de la variable.

Esto es lo que he intentado hasta el momento:

```
$talla= "xg";
if ($fila["codigo_articulo"] no existe){
    ALTER TABLE productos ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS " . $talla. "  not null;
}
```

Comment: favor tomar en consideración esto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7599592/3022312 ( no resuelve tu pregunta, pero puede ser un problema a futuro)

Comment: ¿Qué motor de BD estás usando? Para futuras preguntas comenta el resultado de lo que has intentando: error, no funciona, etc.

Comment: Estoy usando mysqli y la verdad es que no tengo idea de como agregar esa columna si existe o si no

Comment: Algo para tener en cuenta: verificar columnas y si no existen agregarlas, me parece una falla importante en el diseño de la base de datos. La tabla a un futuro podría llegar a tener muchas más columnas de las que realmente necesita.

Comment: El que tengas que agregar una columna a una tabla de forma dinámica en el funcionamiento normal de una aplicación es usualmente señal de que hay un problema en el diseño de tus tablas. Si explicas más en cuanto a tu diseño/aplicación, seguramente se te puede proponer una mejor solución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En `MySQL`, para saber si una columna existe puedes usar [`SHOW COLUMNS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html).

Ejemplo:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM nombre_tabla WHERE Field = "nombreColumna"
```

Aplicado a tu código, podrías hacerlo así:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'mi_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_bd');

$columnName = 'xg';
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM productos WHERE Field = '$columnName'");

if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
    // Si no encontramos la columna, la agregamos
    $mysqli->query("ALTER TABLE productos ADD `$columnName` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En MySql la consulta para agregar una columna es la siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE tutabla ADD tucolumna VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

No te funcionaba porque no estabas especificando el tipo de columna VARCHAR en este caso, y el tamaño 255

Colocas tu consulta en la variable PHP y se la mandas a la base de datos, suponiendo que estás conectado a la misma.

Puedes también indicar si quieres que se agregue después de otra columna de tu tabla.

Ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE ejemplo ADD materno VARCHAR(20) AFTER paterno
```

Agregará una columna llamada `materno` de tipo VARCHAR(20) después de la columna llamada `paterno`

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice algo parecido, creo que te falta añadir el tipo de variable que es en la base de datos (INT, VARCHAR, LONGTEXT...). Solucioné este problema creando una tabla con todos los tipos que se podian crear. Es decir, primero creas una tabla 'campos' con id, nombre y tipo que tenga este aspecto

```
___________campos_________
ID         NOMBRE     TIPO
1           xg         VARCHAR(255)
```

Una vez hecho esto, en la función en la que creas la nueva columna, antes de crearla haces una query como la siguiente:

```
$sql = "SELECT tipo FROM campos WHERE nombre = 'xg';";
```

Ahora nos quedaría (suponiendo que ya estamos conectados a la bbdd con mysqli)

```
$resource = $conn -> query($sql);
$campoDetalles = $resource -> fetch_object();
$infoExtra = $campoDetalles -> tipo;
```

Una vez hecho esto sólo quedaría hacer lo que estabas haciendo con la nueva info

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE <la_tabla> ADD ".$variable." ".$infoExtra.";";
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a ver si existe el campo en tu caso haria algo como :

```
  $talla= "xg";
    if (!isset($fila["codigo_articulo"])){
        $query = "ALTER TABLE productos ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS " . $talla. "  not null";
    }
```